# Embedding something on a webpage

Tags: java, javascript, html, embed

I wrote this nifty little tool that I want to put on my website. (it simplifies radicals)
It was written in java but I'm prepared to rewrite it in another language if I have to.
Anyway I just wanted it to be a simple text box that you can type in and get the answer but that's not really necessary. I'd prefer that it's not a java applet though, as according to my teacher, those are on their way out. A friend of mine suggested something to do with  tags or s or something, but I didn't really follow.

Comment: can you give more details? maybe you can just use ajax and webservices or signalr if you are using .net

Answer (score 0):

> It was written in java but I'm prepared to rewrite it in another language if I have to.

Depending on how it works, you could either post it as a Java Applet (which have been on the way out for quite some time) or you could *possibly* compile it to JavaScript using a tool such as [GWT](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/). I do not have experience with GWT though, so I am not sure if it would be possible to compile something that was not specifically designed to use it from the start - regardless you will probably need to make changes to your code.

Alternatively you could look into rewriting the tool either directly in JavaScript or using another embedded tool such as Flash, Silverlight, etc.

Comment: Okay. If I were to rewrite it in javascript, what method would I employ? Are there IDEs I can use? And can javascript have guis which I could embed?

Comment: @user2170353 - That's kind of a big question. All you really need is a text editor, a web server (if you are doing AJAX), and a browser with a good debugger (like Firefox and Firebug). I also recommend using jQuery to make your life easier. MDN is a good JavaScript reference and W3C is a good HTML/CSS reference. Unfortunately I'm not sure the best way for you to get started...